# LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) incorrect Location

Tags: android, location

```
public Location getLastKnownLocation() {
      LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                  List<String> providers = mLocationManager.getProviders(true);
                  Location bestLocation = null;
                  for (String provider : providers) {
                      Location l = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                      if (l == null) {
                          continue;
                      }
                      if (bestLocation == null
                              || l.getAccuracy() < bestLocation.getAccuracy()) {
                          bestLocation = l;
                      }
                  }
                  if (bestLocation == null) {
                      return null;
                  }
                  return bestLocation;
  }
```

Why this function returns incorrect Location??  The mistake is about 8-9 kilometers

Answer (score 0):

Because getLastKnownLocation doesn't return the current location.  It returns the last location it figured out via that provider.  That position could be an hour old-  it will still return it, if it has it.  If you want to get an accurate location you need to turn on the location provider by calling requestUpdates or requestSingleUpdate, then wait for the onLocationChanged function to be called at least once.  Anything else may be a stale location.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using getLastKnownLocation() :  `location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);`

getLastKnownLocation(String Provider) : Returns a Location indicating the data from the last known location fix obtained from the given provider.

This can be done without starting the provider. Note that this location could be out-of-date, for example if the device was turned off and moved to another location.

From : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29